# Change Terminal.app's Default Shell to BASH

Tags: snow-leopard, terminal, bash

How can I change *Terminal.app*'s default shell to `BASH`?

For some reason, my friend's Mac (10.6.6) defaults to using `TCSH` instead of `BASH`. The obvious remedy is to choose `/bin/bash` as the command to open shells with (as below), but then it fails to load `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (even if I give a `--source` or `--rcfile` parameter).
[image: /bin/bash]

How can I switch it to use `bash` the *right* way?

Comment: Re "For some reason…": The default shell used to be tcsh. Now it's bash, but existing user accounts are not changed when upgrading to a newer Mac OS X. Users with older accounts will need to switch shells themselves.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open System Preferences, select user and right click on its name.
"Advanced options..." will appear. Change shell there.
If you're die hard Apple user, you probably will have to enable right click first.
Depending on your computer model, it can be done under Trackpad or Mouse Preferences.

Comment: This is most likely the best way to do it. Easy, permanent, and doesn't conflict with anything else.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about this. I'm coming from unix word where chsh is the way to go, but I would surely recommend using built-in Mac OS X tool instead.

Comment: You can always control click instead of right click, which is the traditional way to access context menus.

Comment: I don't see the 'user' icon in System Preferences

Comment: I had to "Click the lock to make changes" in order to coerce the context menu to reveal itself. This was on Lion.

Answer (score 7):

By using `chsh` from Terminal. It changes default shell for user. Alternatively you may setup Terminal to use `/bin/bash -l` ... this will cause BASH to behave as login shell, i.e. it will read `.bash_profile`.

Comment: No go for `chsh`; it still gave me `tcsh` as the default shell. However, `/bin/bash -l` does work. I'd like to hear other opinions before I accept it as the _right_ answer, thought.

Answer (score 1):

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal will create login shells even if you choose a custom shell in Startup preferences. So your initial problem should no longer be an issue on Lion. (Although I recommend setting the shell via System Preferences to ensure it's set for the user account and not just for the Terminal application.)