# Why doesn't .bashrc run automatically?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

I put some alias commands in my `.bashrc` file, so that they might be loaded everytime I open a new Terminal window. Yet this doesn't happen.

I have to select `run script:` in the Terminal>Preferences>"*MyDefaultTheme*">Shell prefpane and add:
`source .bashrc && clear` for it to work...

This seems odd since many tutorials only say you just have to add to the `.bashrc` file and all is good.

Note that I don't run in `bash` when using the terminal, I like the other (default) one (don't know what it is) better, because it show me where I am all the time eg:

```
>>d54c6b47b:~ romeo$
```

in stead of:

```
>>bash$
```

In bash all is loaded as should be.

So my question is, why didn't my `.bashrc` file load automatically and did I have to add the option to call it everytime?

Also some tutorial told me to do something like:

```
$alias la=’ls -la’ >> ~/.bashrc
```

which should write the alias to my `.bashrc`, this doesn't work either...

Note that I'm a UNIX novice, so be gentle.

Comment: I think this is very close to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7984/change-terminal-apps-default-shell-to-bash.

Comment: If you are instead using the default `zsh` shell (not i.e: `bash`) configured in 2019+ OS X (currently Catalina), see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338622/192005

Comment: @mmmmmm I've rolled back you edit. The question is clearly about bash, and there even are some recent answers pointing that zsh works differently.

Comment: @nohillside those answers are why I edited. In effect catalina makes the high voted answers wrong but only for catalina. Ie the correct answer rather depends on the os and we often ask what os. Also we might see this is about bash but the new answers show that it is seen about startup scripts and where to set aliases in macos and not looking to see which shell is being used.

Comment: @mmmmmm The answer depends on the shell used, not directly on the OS. I agree that not everybody will be aware of this, but IMHO a new question linking to this one and claiming „it didn’t work“ would be better. The new answers here basically say „maybe you ain‘t using bash, try zsh stuff“.

Comment: @mmmmmm Or you ask a new question „which profiles are used by which shells“, self-answer for bash and zsh, and we close this one as a dupe

Comment: The answer [*What are the functional differences between .profile .bash_profile and .bashrc* - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc#376264) mentioned why macOS behaves differently.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Just put that in your `.profile` file from your home dir and it should work the next time you start a new shell or after you run `source ~/.profile`

This link clearly states the order in which the startup files are read and loaded by the shell:
http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup

Comment: accepted this one because it is has a solution (and it was the first of two near identical posts).

Comment: Down-voted. I recommend against following this advice. The issue is that Terminal creates login shells, and Bash login shells _only_ run the login startup script, not `~/.bashrc`. However, the solution isn't to simply place your `.bashrc` content into the login startup file, because these two files are intended to perform different types of setup. Instead, the canonical setup for Bash is to have your `~/.bash_profile` source your `~/.bashrc` at some appropriate point in the script (usually last).

Comment: I see no other identical post this just says put in the sh file

Comment: If you are instead using the default `zsh` shell (not i.e: `bash`) configured in 2019+ OS X (currently Catalina), see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338622/192005

Answer (score 292):

*Been there, done that.* What I came aware of, OS X doesn't read `.bashrc` file on bash start. Instead, it reads the following files (in the following order):

1. `/etc/profile`
2. `~/.bash_profile`
3. `~/.bash_login`
4. `~/.profile`

See also [Chris Johnsen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3349/chris-johnsen)'s informative and useful comment:

> By default, *Terminal* starts the shell via `/usr/bin/login`, which makes the shell a login shell. On every platform (not just Mac OS X) *bash* does not use `.bashrc` for login shells (only `/etc/profile` and the first of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` that exists and is readable). This is why "put `source ~/.bashrc` in your `.bash_profile`" is standard advice

**I** usually just put the things that I'd normally put in `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile` — has worked so far like a charm.

Comment: By default, *Terminal* starts the shell via `/usr/bin/login`, which makes the shell a login shell.  On every platform (not just Mac OS X) *bash* does not use `.bashrc` for login shells (only `/etc/profile` and the first of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile` that exists and is readable). This is why “put `source ~/.bashrc` in your `.bash_profile`” is standard advice.

Comment: Re "I usually just put the things that I'd normally put in ~/.bashrc to ~/.profile": For maximum compatibility I recommend you follow Chris Johnsen's advice and place anything that you want to apply to non-login shells in ~/.bashrc and add "source ~/.bashrc" to your ~/.bash_profile to run it for login shells. Otherwise, it won't work for sub-shells, or if Terminal changes to create non-login shells, or if you ever use xterm or another terminal program that create non-login shells by default, or if you might want to use the same setup on another OS.

Comment: On a related note, on Mac OS X you should consider having ~/.bashrc run /etc/bashrc to pick up global behaviors. In particular, there's code in /etc/bashrc to update the working directory at each prompt, which is what enables Terminal to display the proxy icon, create new terminals at the same directory, and restore the working directory for Resume and Window Groups.

Comment: For me, sourcing .bashrc from .bash_profile didn't work.  But sourcing .bashrc / .bash_profile from .profile worked.

Comment: Upvote for "This is why "put source ~/.bashrc in your .bash_profile" is standard advice"

Comment: ~/.profile works on iOS!

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan, are you using a shell other than Bash? What does `echo $SHELL` output?

Comment: Nice answer but a bit misinformed. I believe the bash terminal loads only **one** of the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_login`, never all of the them. You can run a simple test by creating the 3 files.  It looks like the bash terminal has the preference of `~/.bash_profile` > `~/.bash_login` > `~/.profile`.  If anyone of them exists, the ones of less preference are skipped. That's why sometimes it is recommended to also source `~/.profile` in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: on El Capitan, I still have to source my `.bashrc` , or `.bash_profile` first to be able to use alias that I set, I dont know where to place my alias to keep it permanent everytime I open a new terminal

Comment: In my case, ~/.profile was not read because I had ~/.bash_profile.

Comment: If you are instead using the default `zsh` shell (not i.e: `bash`) configured in 2019+ OS X (currently Catalina), see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338622/192005

Comment: Can you please clarify the conclusion? Your **quote** is saying _This is why "put source  `~/.bashrc` in your `.bash_profile`" is standard advice_ then **you're** saying: _put in `~/.bashrc` to `~/.profile`_. Are you recommending both? FWIW it only worked for me when I sourced in the `~/.profile`.

Comment: @Honey This answer seems to suggest “either”. (Your approach is IMO better, though.)

Comment: This is the correct answer for Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 35):

I put everything into `~/.bashrc` and just `source ~/.bashrc` in .profile.

This allows screen and xterm (and i guess tmux) sessions to inherit my environment as non-login sessions only run `.bashrc`, whereas login sessions (eg terminal or iTerm) only run `.profile`.

Comment: This is my approach.  This way I can maintain a .bashrc that works on both systems... and I can put any mac specific stuff or stuff like aliases that are only for work (where I use the mac the most) in my .bash_profile file.

Comment: Note that `.profile` is common to several shells and should only contain POSIX-compatible sh code. If it sources `.bashrc` it arguably contains Bash-specific code (the existence of the `.bashrc` file is Bash-specific). I recommend renaming your `.profile` to `.bash_profile` since you're using it in a Bash-specific way. Or, put generic code in `.profile` and create a `.bash_profile` that sources `.profile` and `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 24):

There are two scenarios:

1. You are using Linux
2. You are using Mac Os X

For both you want to source `~/.bashrc` in your profile that gets loaded, or sourced, when your shell for your terminal starts.

---

LINUX

In Linux, `~/.profile` is automatically source in your shell when it starts. So, if you go to your terminal and type `cd ~; ls -A`, you will see all of your files and directories in your home directory (`/home/usrname/`). You should see a file called `.profile`. This is the file that is automatically "sourced" when you start the terminal.

If you want to add aliases and functions to `~/.bashrc` (which is what I do), then you should (inside of `~/.profile` add an if statement that checks if `~/.bashrc` is a non-empty file and then source it.

To check if your `~/.profile` already does this enter `nano ~/.profile`. This will open it up in a text editor (you can use gedit if you know you have it or even vim if you know how to use it). You may get an empty text file (you shouldn't), but if you do simply proceed. If you do not see a line *anywhere* that says `source ~/.bashrc`, then enter the following lines somewhere (put it in a reasonable place like at the end or beginning and not in the middle of an if statement):

```
if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc;
fi
```

This checks if `~/.bashrc` is a non-empty file (with if `[ -s ~/.bashrc ]`), and if it is such, it sources it. Pretty simple. Now, you can add any valid alias, function, variable, etc to `~/.bashrc`.

---

MAC OS X

By default (prior to 2019 Catalina), Mac OS X sources `~/.bash_profile`. To be able to add things to `~/.bashrc` (which is, again, what I do in OS X, as well), then you follow the same procedure as linux. In the terminal enter `cd ~; nano .bash_profile`. Check for a line that says `source ~/.bashrc` and if it's not there add the if statement above (`if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc; fi`).

---

NOTES

When writing an if statement, be sure to leave spaces between basically everything (for example `if [ -s ~/.bashrc]; then echo "found"; fi` does not work because there is no space beween `~/.bashrc` and `]` - the interpreter will think this is one word).

If you want to figure out how to check for stuff in an if statement better, go to terminal and enter `man \[`; this essentially gives you the run-down of an if statement. For example, `if [ -f /path/to/file ]; then echo "it's a file"; else echo "not a file"; fi` checks if `/path/to/file` is a file and if it is prints to stdout accordingly. I always reference this as well for easier-on-the-eyes and quick reference: [7.2. File test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

I hope this helps. I remember how confused I was when I started all of this stuff (which wasn't too long ago); so, good luck with your future UNIX endeavours!

Comment: On linux, `.profile` is only sourced if your shell is a login shell, otherwise `.bashrc` is sourced

Comment: If you are instead using the default `zsh` shell (not i.e: `bash`) configured in 2019+ OS X (currently Catalina), see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338622/192005

Answer (score 21):

By the way, if you have activated ZSH, it replaces bash!

So all those `~/.bashrc` files don't get loaded.

You have to set your aliases in `~/.zshrc` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why this had a downvote. Everything else wasn't working for me and I didn't think that ZSH was the problem.

Comment: And on 2019+ Mac OS X (Catalina currently), `zsh` is the default (no activation necessary) shell (instead of `bash`) ;)

Comment: tnq :) 01234567

Comment: my man..........

Comment: 2022, ohhh, man!

Comment: MVP right here, making my transition from PC -> Mac for work much more tolerable :)

Answer (score 11):

Sourcing .profile in .bash_profile did it for me

```
echo 'source ~/.profile' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Sourcing .profile in .bash_profile is a great thing to do, but that alone wouldn't cause .bashrc to be run by login shells. Your .profile must've already sourced .bashrc, which could cause problems if you ever use a shell other than bash. Most Mac users never will, but if you do for some reason, remember this. :)

Comment: To expand on what @TerryN said: be sure to source `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` and not from `.profile`. `.bash_profile` is Bash-specific and should source the other two.

Comment: In 2019+ (Mac OS X Caltalina installs), the default shell is `zsh`. It does not source `.bash*` files automatically and starts with `.profile`.

Comment: Yes, osX Catalina defaults to `zsh` - but @ingyhere are you sure that sourcing starts with `~/.profile`?  It seemed in my case (on my Catalina) it did not, and I have instead been successfully using just `~/.zshrc` (per https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/338622/192005).

Comment: @cellepo I think it depends on whether there is a `~/.zprofile`. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/457892/142375) cites the order from docs for zsh. Also, `~/.profile` seems to be loaded by a number of shells, so it appears more universal.

Answer (score 6):

I found that after installing rvm (auto-installer, no manual edits) it had created a `~/.bash_login` file for itself, where I previously never had one.

However, this mean that my `~/.profile` setups and aliases no longer got loaded! Lots of shortcuts disappeared. I thought they ran sequentially, not exclusively :-/

I added

```
. ~/.profile
```

to `~/.bash_login` to chain things as I expected.

Comment: +1, this is situation I had.  I found that either .bash_login or .bash_profile will prevent .profile from being executed...  No idea why bash feels the need to have so many conflicting startup files.

Comment: `.profile` is common to several different shells and should only contain POSIX-compatible sh code. `.bash_profile` is Bash-specific and can contain Bash-specific code. In general, if you're using Bash you should prefer `.bash_profile` unless you are careful to ensure that your startup code does not contain anything that depends on Bash. Whatever program created `.bash_login` probably did so because it contains Bash-specific code, but it should have included code to source `.profile` if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

Putting...

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

...in `~/.bashrc`, and then source `~/.bashrc` into my `~/.bash_profile`  didn't work for the Terminal program that comes installed.

But then I went to the menu drop-down **Edit > Profile Preferences**, **Title and Command** tab, and selected **Run command as a login shell** from the command section of that page.

After doing so, starting a new terminal shows the desired result when I type

```
 type rvm|head -1
```

i.e. "rvm is a function". It did not do that until I made this change, and it's the only change I made after the `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` changes described in other answers here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me tell you that `~/.bashrc` is the file which is executed every time a second shell is called up (when running a shell script, for instance), and `~/.profile` is called on every login.

So I recommend you to write `. ~/.bashrc` command in your `~/.profile` file, and this command will execute the bashrc file every time you login.

Comment: when .profile get executed on login it automatically execute the .bashrc file.

Comment: so .bashrc gets executed indirectly at every login

Comment: bashrc is for non-login shells. bash_profile/bash_login/profile/whatever else is for login shells. This is a source of a huge amount of contention, involving what is and isn't a login shell (a screen/tmux session for example, a terminal within a desktop environment, etc.). It's not necessarily the "second shell". It's a matter of shell entry.

Comment: If you ever use a shell that isn't Bash, doing what you describe might cause you problems. .profile applies to all shells and .bashrc might contain language that some other shells don't understand. Instead of .profile, put what you wrote in .bash_profile. (Also, make the first thing .bash_profile does be "source .profile".)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after installing rbenv on my remote server (Digital Ocean) Ubuntu 16.04.

It somehow created `~/.bash_profile`. It's the same `~/.bashrc` on an OS X system.

And Ubuntu started to read only `~/.bash_profile`, but not `~/.bashrc` as it should.

So I just backed up my data in `~/.bash_profile` with this:

```
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile.bak
```

And renamed the old `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`

```
mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile
```

It worked for me. After my ssh login I have everything loaded in `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help anyone else...

Make sure you're editing the right `.bashrc` file for the right user. I had a similar issue using Vagrant. After running `vagrant ssh` my `.bashrc` file was not being run. The solution was simple in that I thought vagrant was logging in with the user named vagrant, and I was actually logging in as another user. So I was editing the wrong `.bashrc` file. After editing the correct `.bashrc` file my aliases were recognized.

Answer (score -1):

On Debian `.bashrc` is sourced from `.profile` this way:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

So I use this approach on other systems, where `.bashrc` is not sourced. You don't have to worry that the other shells may source Bash code, as the condition on the first line prevents it.

Comment: Why would another shell execute Bash specific startup scripts like?  `.bashrc` is sourced only for a login shell where as `.bash_profile` is read for all interactive shells (i.e. Terminal)     `.profile` is only read when `.bash_profile` doesn’t exist.  macOS ≠ Linux so there’s no need for `.bashrc` and the script there isn’t for Debian, but for systems running XWindows/PTTY type logins. macOS does not do this.

Comment: Yes, `.profile` is only read when `.bash_profile` doesn’t exist. And `.bash_profile` usually does not exist. And those who source `.bashrc` from `.profile` without `if [ "$BASH" ] ...` will source `.bashrc` while invoking the other shells that read `.profile`, which I think is undesirable.

Comment: Since macOS doesn’t use those files by default, the only way they would show up is if someone put them in there incorrectly. Please note that you’re applying a Linux/Xorg convention to macOS and it is totally different.

Comment: It's not "totally different", shells are the same programs whatever OS they're running on, that files might be put there deliberately and not "incorrectly". As for no reason to use `.bashrc` - that's not correct, it's used for non-login shells (BTW you confused it in the first comment, actually `*profile` files are for login shells)

Comment: They”re different enough.  Like I already said, Linux uses Xorg which require a login shell whereas macOS doesn’t.  Since you can remote into macOS and get a login shell, .`bash_profile` covers everything,  Using `.bashrc` and `.profile` only serve to add unneeded complexity.

Comment: Incorrect. In every aspect. What I can say.. Just `man bash`. "Linux uses Xorg ..." It does not in general. It's just a special case. I think I quit conversation here, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

To keep with the OSX style login `.profile` and support the normal bash behavior `.bashrc` you can use a `.bashrc` file if you switch between regular nix and OSX by providing a symbolic link to your `.bashrc` file called `.bash_profile`. Just make sure this file doesn't exist already before trying this, but this is how I do it.

```
ln -s .bashrc .bash_profile
```

Comment: By doing this linking between 2 differents shell initialisation script you are loosing a necessary separation of function.
One day or another you will need an initialisation at the session level (`.bash_profile`) and an initialisation different at each shell level (`.bashrc`).

Answer (score -2):

/etc/bashrc is for global profiles on mac systems.
You can add: alias ls="ls -G" to the top of this file
and your good, everyone will have colorized files and folders
on the system so you will not have to set anything extra for each individual user. You will also notice along with "sudo su -" to root from yourself you will still have colorized files and folders with no extra headaches.

Another fun tip: When using mac's Iterm2, importing color profiles will render the coloring of the files and folders immediately according to your color scheme after having this "/etc/bashrc" option set.