# Why must I source .bashrc every time I open terminal for aliases to work?

Tags: bash, alias

I added this line into my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
alias myserver='ssh davidfaux@davidfaux.com'
```

However, when I open terminal and run `myserver`, terminal complains that

```
-bash: myserver: command not found
```

When I source my .bashrc file, however, (`. .bashrc`), the alias works.

Nonetheless, I do not want to source the file every time I open terminal for the alias to work. How do I make that happen?

Comment: [This comment](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically#comment13715_13019) explains the reason for this. That question tells you how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know that starting the shell executes those files in order. Indeed, adding `. .bashrc` into `.bash_profile` works.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw can/should you change your comment to an answer? That way it can be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In short, you are putting your aliases in the wrong file `.bashrc`, that is why you need to keep running source to get the aliases working in any new login terminal instances.

From Chris Johnsen's comment at [Why doesn't .bashrc run automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically#comment13715_13019)

> > By default, Terminal starts the shell via /usr/bin/login, which makes the shell a login shell. On every platform (not just Mac OS X) bash does not use .bashrc for login shells (only /etc/profile and the first of .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile that exists and is readable). This is why “put source ~/.bashrc in your .bash_profile” is standard advice.

For more information, see the manual page for `bash`:

```
man bash
```

Then look under the INVOCATION section.

Comment: Do I need to reboot in order to get things working? Because I added `source ~/.bashrc` to my .bash_profile, but I'm still facing the same issue...

Comment: No in most cases you just need to open a new terminal window for the changes to take effect, the changes will only take effect in the newly opened window.

Answer (score 14):

You can always put

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ];then
    source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

into the file `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` on mac I think.

Oooor, you could just put your stuff in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This is noted in the other answer - why are you unsure about these things?

Comment: Please read this very similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12993/22003
and add there any improvment.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Wait; do you want me to comment on the other page or update my answer based on the other question?

Comment: @Mark I was just thinking in a very hypothetical sense - like what if someone's terminal process didn't know to source .profile? Their terminal probably would not start in the first place, but it is still possible.... like if someone was hacking around at their /usr/bin/login or something.

Comment: → Dylan: please read this very similar question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12993/22003 and you'll find an answer to your "maybe?".

Comment: Oh; ok. While there's probably a 99.9999999999% chance that profile will be source it hypothetically could not be. I could take it out if you want me to.