# terminal custom commands source every time

Tags: command-line, macos, iterm, alias

After following this [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42537/why-must-i-source-bashrc-every-time-i-open-terminal-for-aliases-to-work) I added all my startup/alias commands to `~/.bashrc` file and in `~/.bash_profile` I added `source ~/.bashrc`

But still my aliases are not working. I have to manually source `~/.bash_profile` overtime (with `source ~/.bash_profile`).

My .bashrc file:

```
alias km='cd /Users/apple/Desktop/km'
```

and my .bash_profile file

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
source ~/.bashrc
```

In my user directory I only have following files:
[image]

My iterm2 profile:
[image]

UPDATE:
For me this solution actually [worked](https://superuser.com/a/436425)

Comment: is your terminal configured to launch a **login** shell?

Comment: Yes I guess its using login shell. Please check screenshot attached above

Comment: Try running Terminal, the built in one not iTerm. Does it load your alias?

Comment: no it didnt work :(

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post an answer and accept it. Make sure you include proper acknowledgement of the original author, a link, and the most important information from said post. This helps future users by allowing them to easily see that the problem is solved even if they miss the last line.

Comment: Are you using Bash or ZSH? You have ZSH configuration files in your $HOME. If you are using ZSH then this would explain why your Bash aliases, etc, aren't being read. Double check by opening an iTerm/Terminal window and typing `echo $SHELL`

Comment: its ZSH
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after all struggle the only solution which worked for me is by executing `source ~/.bashrc` every time when I open my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work by using .login and .profile.
The way it works is .login is sourced by every login shell and  it in turn sources .profile

In .login I have:

```
. .profile
```

and in .profile I have:

```
function pgrep(){
ps -axww | grep -i "$1" | grep -v "[p ]grep"
}

function diskspc(){
sudo find / -iname "*$1*" -print0 | xargs -0 du -chs
}


JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.Framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home"
export JAVA_HOME

alias rsync="rsync --stats --progress"

alias forcequit="open -a iForce\ Quit"

alias ls="/bin/ls -FG"
alias ll="ls -la"
alias gls="gls --color=auto -aF"

alias find="/usr/bin/find"

. /sw/bin/init.sh

LC_ALL='C'
export LC_ALL

alias locate2='if [ $((`date +%s`-`eval $(stat -s /var/db/locate.database); echo $st_mtime`)) -gt 3600 ]; then echo "locate: db is too old!">/dev/stderr; sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb; fi; locate -i'

alias flocate="/sw/bin/locate.fink --database=/sw/var/locatedb"

LOCATE_PATH=/var/db/locate.database
#LOCATE_PATH=/sw/var/locatedb:/var/db/locate.database
#LOCATE_PATH=/sw/var/locatedb
export LOCATE_PATH

#LESS_IS_MORE=1
#export LESS_IS_MORE
```

Of course,feel free to use or not the stuff in my .profile.