# sourcing .bash_profile from .bashrc breaks macvim shell

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm

I read [Why doesn't .bashrc run automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically) about sourcing `.bash_profile` from `.bashrc` and adjusted my config to match this. I am using iTerm2 as my terminal.

Unfortunately, when I do this, my MacVim shell breaks - backspace doesn't work and I have strange characters all over the place. Note the characters`?1034h` before the prompt and the `K` that appears when hitting the backspace key.

[image]

My `.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

My `.bashrc`:

```
alias ll='ls -al'
# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

If copy the settings from `.bashrc` into `.bash_profile` and delete `.bashrc` then the shell in MacVim works fine.

Any idea why MacVim shell breaks sourcing `.bash_profile` from `.bashrc`?

Comment: They look like color codes.

Comment: @mostruash I understand what the `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` is doing, I just don't get why sourcing '`bashrc` from `bash_profile` breaks `macvim`

Comment: before you start macvim what does `echo $TERM` show in both cases

Comment: Also, what does `echo $TERM` show when called from within the shell spawned by macvim, again in both cases?

Comment: I'm just giving a hint, are you sure that you put that `CLICOLOR` into your bash profile? If you copy bashrc content into bash profile without skipping anything, then I have no idea. Good luck.

Comment: My suspicion currently is that the shell spawned by `macvim` only reads `.bashrc` (and not `.bash_profile`) because it is not a login shell.

Comment: @patrix in both cases the output is `xterm-256color`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676026/macvim-shell-sh-only-displays-character-codes-escape-sequences the initial `?1034h` characters are the colour codes I've set up in my `.bashrc`.

When calling `echo $TERM` from `macvim` the result is `dumb`. It looks like the terminal is unable to interpret certain escape sequences.

Details on how to adjust the `.bashrc` to accommodate (taken from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676355/783836):

> If you would like to use a color prompt on the command line, but not
>   in MacVim you can fix this in `~/.bashrc` by setting PS1 differently
>   when inside vim (from [here][1])
>
> ```
> if [ $VIM ]; then
>         export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
> fi
> ```