# Change my shell to a different bash version at /usr/local/bin/bash?

Tags: terminal, bash, command-line

How can I set my `/usr/local/bin/bash` (which is the 4.2 version that allows auto-completion of 'cd to directory with directory name') to be my default bash for a new window instead of my regular (v3.2.48) version.

I can type `/usr/local/bin/bash` and get into it but that's not the default for a new Terminal window which is what I want.

Comment: Is this what you seek? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7984/change-terminal-apps-default-shell-to-bash

Comment: No, this is about specifying a new shell entirely (likely an updated version of the bash shell), not simply about changing to use bash.

Comment: Oh yeah - thanks for digging up how to add a custom shell to the list of ones that are trusted by the OS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know if this will populate in the terminal / advanced user account locations, but "The Way This Has Worked For Years"™ in Linux-land is that you must update `/etc/shells` with the path to the shell location, and then use `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash username` to use it.

Simply running `chsh` without modification to `/etc/shells` should cause an error indicating you've chosen an invalid shell, in case you're curious.

`/etc/shells` is a root-owned file, so you must use sudo in tandem with an editor in order to modify it. I hope you're comfortable doing that, else I would highly advise against trying out a non-default shell :).

Summary (steps):

- `brew install bash`, then
- `sudo vi /etc/shells` and add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to the list, then
- `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash [your_username]` and restart your terminal in order for your changes to take place

Answer (score 18):

1) go to "System Preferences" > "Users & Groups"

2) click the padlock icon and authenticate

3) right-click the icon for your user and select "Advanced Options..."

4) change the value for "Login shell" from "/bin/bash" to your preferred shell

[image]

Comment: this didn't work for me today (3 years on) but below did so switching accept.